# how to pause CPLEX during a B&B execution and feed it with a solution?

Tags: cplex

I would like to find a way to feed CPLEX with solutions while it is solving a minimzation MIP. These solutions come from heuristics that I run in parallel to CPLEX. The whole approach is modeled in Java and I call CPLEX using IloCplex.

I tried to set a time limit on CPLEX and, once paused, feed the new solution to the CPLEX model using MIPStarts. However, when I run again the CPLEX model, it says the solutions I provided are not feasible even though I'm sure they are. Actually, CPLEX accepts these solutions when I completely restart the model, which is not what I want because by doing this the exploration of the b&b tree starts all over again form the root node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than stopping CPLEX entirely in order to provide a mip-start, you may want to use callbacks and inject solutions during the search.  The relevant section of the User's Manual is https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/UsrMan/topics/progr_adv/callbacks/introCallbacks.html, and the reference for the Java API is at https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refjavacplex/html/ilog/cplex/IloCplex.Callback.html.

It seems odd that a solution would be accepted as a mip-start at the beginning of the search, but not when the search is already started and CPLEX is interrupted.  If you can reproduce this behavior using the CPLEX Interactive, I suggest you post a question at https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/forum?id=11111111-0000-0000-0000-000000002059 and attach the files that would allow to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I implemented my approach using a heuristic callback and I experience the same problem. I use the setSolution(vars, vals) function to feed the solution I get from my heuristics, and when I do so I do not get any error or warning. However, when the CPLEX model continues running after the callback it simply does not take into account my solution (the solution is feasible because it works when fed as mip-start in a new model). Do you know if this solution is supposed to be considered immediately?, or is there a time lag before it is considered by CPLEX?.

Comment: Please have a look at https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=8d15b4a9-aa3b-48d4-a824-9ef66b138812&permalinkReplyUuid=b9c2789a-5af6-4267-b9e0-8cecd3dccfbf. Specifically, you want to follow Daniel's steps mentioned in his first answer.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to bypass all checks you may use nocheck as the MIP start effort level

> NoCheck  CPLEX accepts the MIP start without any checks.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.ide.help/refjavaopl/html/ilog/opl/IloCplex.MIPStartEffort.html